# Replace NA value with a bunch of randomly generated values in R

Tags: r, random, filter, replace, na

I want to filter my Title column and then replace the NA values in Age column with a bunch of randomly generated values(within min and max age range). I tried the following command

`titanic_df4 <- titanic_df3 %>% filter(titanic_df3$Title=='Mr.') %>% mutate(Age = replace_na(Age, runif(1, min=14, max=57)))`

but it just replace the na value with one specific value within the range. What should I do?

Tried this

```
titanic_df4 <- titanic_df3 %>% filter(titanic_df3$Title=='Mr.') %>% mutate(Age = replace_na(Age, runif(1, min=14, max=57)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace_na` only works for single values. From the `?replace_na` help page:

> If `data` is a vector, `replace` takes a single value. This single value replaces all of the `NA` values in the vector.

Instead we can generate enough values for the whole vector and use `coalesce()` to fill in the `NA` values with those generated values.

```
titanic_df3 %>%
  ## Title not titanic_df3$Title
  filter(Title == 'Mr.') %>% 
  mutate(Age = coalesce(Age, runif(n(), min=14, max=57)))
```

Comment: I tried to change the value


Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Age = replace_na(Age, runif(sum(is.na(Age)), min = 14, max = 57))`.
Caused by error in `replace_na()`:
! Replacement for `data` must be length 1, not length 57.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Edits incoming.

Comment: Also, don't use `data$column` inside `dplyr` functions - it can mess up grouping operations. They all expect unquoted column names

Comment: OK got it. But now the old df is not updating.

titanic_df3 <- titanic_df3 %>% filter(Title=='Mr.') %>% mutate(Age = round(coalesce(Age, runif(n(), min=min(Age, na.rm=TRUE), max=max(Age, na.rm=TRUE)))))

just shows the columns where Title = Mr. instead of the whole df

Comment: Yes, that's what `filter(Title=='Mr.')`, it keeps only the rows where the Title is "Mr". Is that not what you want?

Comment: This is what I want. I have multiple type of Title in the title column (Mr, Mrs, Miss, etc) I want to filter each type and then replace the NA value in Age column of each type from a randomly generated value. 
At the end, the df will have no na value in age and will show all other attributes and variables. Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: That sounds like you **don't** want to filter because filtering drops rows. Instead, make the replacement dependent on the Title, e.g., `titanic_df3 %>% mutate(Age = coalesce(Age, case_when(Title == "Mr." ~ runif(n(), min=14, max=57), Title == "Mrs." ~ ... )))`

Comment: Yah I figured it out. I used groupby. I think that works too 

titanic_df5 <- titanic_df2 %>% group_by(Title) %>% mutate(Age = round(coalesce(Age, runif(n(), min=min(Age, na.rm=TRUE), max=max(Age, na.rm=TRUE)))))

Thnaks btw.